# Inject a string at the end of every row of a ResultSet except the last one

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I am querying a table and it returns an unknown number of rows. I'm trying to build a dynamic query that goes something like this:

```
sql_string = "select * from table where ";
while (res.next()) {
    sql_string += res.getString(1) + "union"
}
etc etc.
```

Essentially, `res.next()` refers to a previously executed query, and I am trying to build a query by substituting values from it's resultset. The final query should be something like:

`select * from table where cond1 
 UNION
 select * from table where cond2`, but it returns something like:

`select * from table where cond1
 UNION
 select * from table where cond2 UNION`

What is the best way to achieve the desired result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is `ResultSet.isLast()` function you could call to check if your suffix should be appended, but it is optional (might not be implemented by your JDBC provider), and also may be expensive.

A better idea may be to append the extra stuff at the beginning of the loop rather than at the end:

```
String originalSql = sql_string + " ";
String append = " "; 
while(res.next()) {
   sql_string += append + res.getString(1);            
   append = " union " + originalSql;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it returns: `select * from table where cond1 UNION cond2`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot about the original string :) Fixing ...
Actually, your original code does the same as well: the sql is not repeated for every condition it appends.

Comment: Worked like a charm! :D Thanks! :)

Comment: And I know that the code I have posted did not work either. I had tried several combinations and one of the combinations that I'd tried led to that result. Thank you for leading me to the right path :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `"union"` at the front and skip the first iteration. ex:

```
sql_string = "select * from table where ";
String ret = sql_string;
boolean first = true;
while (res.next()) {
    if(!first){
        ret += " union " + sql_string;
    }else{
        first = false;
    }
    ret += res.getString(1);
}
```

Comment: As with @Dima's answer, I tried this, and it returns: `select * from table where cond1 UNION cond2`